# Openbravo's mandatory attributes not treated as mandatory

Tags: openbravo

all.

I am new to Openbravo implementation and need lots of support from experienced Openbravo implementors.
I am currently trying to implement the latest Openbravo (3.0PR16Q3) and had an issue where the mandatory attributes are not treated as mandatory (eg: in Purchase Order, Goods Receipt). Openbravo just let the lines created with those attributes left unspecified. What have I missed?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: either those mandatory fields have default values, or u missed some configuration. There is no way it can happen.

Comment: The product which has the attributes do not have "Attribute Set Value" filled in Product window and therefore neither the "Use Attribute Set Value As" field. I have checked thoroughly but still can not find any improper configuration. The Attribute Set Value field in Sales Order line is not in yellow (like other mandatory fields). I also went to Windows, Tabs, and Fields menu and did not see any setting that can be used to set the Attribute Set Value as mandatory.